# What is the type of this function definition "twice f x = f (f x)"

Tags: haskell

This is an excerice question from a book I'm reading now, so what is the type of this definition:

```
twice f x = f (f x)
```

I understand how the function should work, but I could not figure out the 
right syntax for it,
It takes two arguments, the first is a function and the second is a basic type I think and apply the function twice, one for x and one for the return of (f x) , this is what is was trying to do but obviously it's a wrong syntax

`twice :: (f -> a) -> a`

Can you help me find the type?

Comment: What did you try *yourself*?

Comment: i tried a lot actually but i couldn't figure it out, this is the last exercise so it is the hardest

Comment: Can you at least share a "path of thought", [edit] your question.

Comment: @ahmed.py, try `:t twice` in `ghci`

Comment: sorry i'm not a native english speaker so i didn not understand your question at first, i understand how the function should work but i could not figure out the syntax for it
it take tow argument the first is a function and the second a abasic type i think and applay the function twice one for x and one for the return of (f x)

Comment: guys i spent almost an hour trying to solve this , forgive if i can't express myself right

Comment: I have added your attempt into the question. When asking questions here, show what you have tried. You can [edit] your questions. You may want to try defining the function, compiling, and see what errors it gives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should deducting type of `twice` starting with it's parameters.

Start with `x`, it has type `x :: _`, but we have no idea what it is, lets call it's type `a`: `x :: a`.

Then we have `f`, it's a function, from `f x` we can tell it accepts one argument of type `a`: `f :: a -> _`, let's call new unknown type `b`: `f :: a -> b`.

So `f x` should be of type `b`: `(f x) :: b` right?

But from `f (f x)` we can tell that `(f x)` should be `a`, so we can guess that `a` and `b` are actually the same type, so we can drop `b` and tell that `f :: a -> a`.

And now we can tell what type `twice` is: it's a function that takes `a -> a` function and value of type `a` and returns result of the first argument function (so `a` again).

So we have `twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

Comment: thanks a lot, thats exactly what i was thinking of but with out the right syntax , i was trying to do this `twice :: (f -> a)  -> a`